# Erro ao tentar reiniciar NGINX no Terminal Service para instalação de SSL Let's Encrypt

Tags: nginx

Estou tentando realizar este passo a passo

[how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Com a finalidade de instalar um certificado ssl gratuito [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Meu problema:

Não consigo reiniciar o [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) nem iniciar o serviço manualmente.
para prosseguir com o passo a passo da instalação.

> Step 2 — Setting up Nginx

Tentando reiniciar.

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
nginx.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

Tentando inciar manualmente.

```
sudo service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Verificando Estado da configuração.

```
 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Verificando log.

```
  sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Log.

```
2019/07/11 12:27:16 [notice] 3617#3617: signal process started
2019/07/11 12:27:16 [error] 3617#3617: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:35:42 [emerg] 3816#3816: still could not bind()
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2019/07/11 12:37:28 [emerg] 4085#4085: still could not bind()
```

Verificando configuração

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Estado da configuração.

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.sistemasjca.com.br;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Comment: Tenho essa dúvida também. Travo sempre nesta parte.

Comment: [Esse passo a passo aqui](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx) é mais simples e é da propria certbot. No passo 4 você pode fazer assim por exemplo `sudo certbot --nginx -d meudominio.com -d www.meudominio.com -d abc.meudominio.com`